# How do you randomize the order of a fixed set of numbers in dart?

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I wonder if someone can help me with something that’s driving me up the wall.

I’m very new to flutter and the dart language. Working on a basic personal project as I progress through a Udemy course.

It’s called ‘Bushy Bingo’ – The below is the UI (set aside the layout issues for now)
What I want is for the order of the animals to shuffle when the user clicks the shuffle button. So you get a randomized game each time.

[image: Bushy Bingo UI]

The animals are all custom widgets I’ve created which sit within a ‘Table’ widget, 4 Table Rows, 4 children a piece to create the 4 x 4 grid.

My thinking is that I need to

1. Assign a ‘positionNumber’ value as an into to each cell of the
   grid
2. Create an ‘animalIndex’ map containing my 16 animals
3. Write a for loop function, which creates a tableOrder from
   scratch on the following logic..

   A - For 16 times...

   B - Generate a random number between zero and the length of my animalIndex

   C - Take the corresponding entry from my animalIndex and add it as a new entry to my tableOrder list

   D - Remove the entry from the animalIndex

Assuming that's reasonable logic, i cannot get it to work with dart. Please see the below screenshot to see the issue

[image: BushyBingoProblem]

If anyone could let me know where I'm going wrong it would be massively appreciated. Maybe my whole approach is wrong. (I've been wrong before ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** *I'm really sorry, I didnt mean to step on any toes. You probably put alot of work into what you have already. Your approach could be used obviously, but its a bit over the top for what you wanted to achieve. That's how I came to my answer. If that is not what you are looking for then I hope someone else can help you with the generation of your numbers etc..*

I dont have enough reputation yet to comment, so I'm doing it like this. The best way would be to make an animal class and build a list from there.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Animal {
  String name;
  Image animalImage;

  Animal({this.name, this.animalImage});
}
```

Then use that to make a list:

```
List getAnimals() {
  return [
    Animal(
      name: "duck",
      animalImage: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
    ),
    Animal(
      name: "elephant",
      animalImage: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
    ),
  ];
}
```

Once you have that you can put that in your listviewBuilder. After they press the button you can make a function that takes that list and shuffles it:

[example: shuffle docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/shuffle.html)
[example: other shuffle stuff](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/shuffle.html)

This way you can always add or remove animals. With the class you can add or remove extra data. And since it's a list it will have its own index id's so you can order it, shuffle it, do whatever you want.

ListviewBuilder example. There are ways to make a gridviewbuilder so that's covered too. You can style the widget anyway you want. [Gridview example](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/grid-lists)

```
ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: getAnimals().length,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    var _data = getAnimals()[index];

                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(_data.name),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  })
```

Comment: You are a legend! Step on my toes all you want. I only ever want the simplest solution. I had no idea there was a shuffle function! Defintely better than the rabbithole i was going down. Thanks so much :)

Comment: No problem man. If you have any issues or questions, dont hessitate to ask. It's alot better than wasting time trying something that could be done easier. I learned this the hard way.. xD